# Getting AVAST alert during program update/upgrade in Kali Linux

Tags: malware, linux, virus, virtualization, kali-linux

**So i started to use VirtualBox in windows 10 and i would like to know if those alert from my windows 10 security program (avast antivirus), during my installation/upgrading of TheHarvester program at virtualmachine Kali Linux of VirtualBox will cause any threat or harm to my personal computer? ( I am really concerned about the others getting chance hacking into my pc XD )**

And here are the blocked stuff from avast logs:

1)ELF:AirCrack-B [Tool] ([http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/a/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng_1.6-4_amd64.deb|>data.tar.xz|>data.tar|>.\usr\bin\aircrack-ng](http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/a/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng_1.6-4_amd64.deb%7C%3Edata.tar.xz%7C%3Edata.tar%7C%3E.%5Cusr%5Cbin%5Caircrack-ng))

2)ELF:Flooder-NY [Trj] ([http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/e/ettercap/ettercap-common_0.8.3-7_amd64.deb|>data.tar.xz|>data.tar|>.\usr\lib\ettercap\ec_dos_attack.so](http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/e/ettercap/ettercap-common_0.8.3-7_amd64.deb%7C%3Edata.tar.xz%7C%3Edata.tar%7C%3E.%5Cusr%5Clib%5Cettercap%5Cec_dos_attack.so))

3)Win32:GenMaliciousA-GHG [PUP] ([http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/m/mimikatz/mimikatz_2.2.0-git20200208-0kali1_all.deb|>data.tar.xz|>data.tar|>.\usr\share\windows-resources\mimikatz\Win32\mimidrv.sys](http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/m/mimikatz/mimikatz_2.2.0-git20200208-0kali1_all.deb%7C%3Edata.tar.xz%7C%3Edata.tar%7C%3E.%5Cusr%5Cshare%5Cwindows-resources%5Cmimikatz%5CWin32%5Cmimidrv.sys))

4)Win64:Malware-gen ([http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/r/responder/responder_3.0.0.0-0kali1_all.deb|>data.tar.xz|>data.tar|>.\usr\share\responder\tools\MultiRelay\bin\mimikatz.exe](http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/r/responder/responder_3.0.0.0-0kali1_all.deb%7C%3Edata.tar.xz%7C%3Edata.tar%7C%3E.%5Cusr%5Cshare%5Cresponder%5Ctools%5CMultiRelay%5Cbin%5Cmimikatz.exe))

5)BV:Downloader-MA [Trj] ([http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/s/set/set_8.0.3-0kali1_all.deb|>data.tar.xz|>data.tar|>.\usr\share\set\src\core\setcore.py](http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/s/set/set_8.0.3-0kali1_all.deb%7C%3Edata.tar.xz%7C%3Edata.tar%7C%3E.%5Cusr%5Cshare%5Cset%5Csrc%5Ccore%5Csetcore.py))

6)Win32:PUP-gen [PUP] ([http://kali.download/kali/pool/non-free/w/wce/wce_1.42-beta-0kali3_all.deb|>data.tar.xz|>data.tar|>.\usr\share\windows-resources\wce\getlsasrvaddr.exe](http://kali.download/kali/pool/non-free/w/wce/wce_1.42-beta-0kali3_all.deb%7C%3Edata.tar.xz%7C%3Edata.tar%7C%3E.%5Cusr%5Cshare%5Cwindows-resources%5Cwce%5Cgetlsasrvaddr.exe))

Answer (score 1):

Kali Linux contains a ton of malicious tools, so it's expected that antivirus software complains about them. This can happen if it scans the network traffic during upgrade, which is probably the case now, as the upgrade uses plain HTTP connections. Some antivirus software might also scan the disk images of virtual machines. Both may cause problems to or break your Kali installation, so it might be a good idea to add some exceptions.

Despite technically malware, these aren't a security problem per se, but they are powerful tools that may cause problems if you don't use them wisely. You might end up weakening your security if you attack against your host machine.

Comment: Shared folders are also often the problem in such cases. That means if, for example, files in Kali go into such a mounted directory they will become visible on the host at the same time. Since, as already mentioned, Kali has a large number of programs with payloads that are classified as malware, the AV software then takes action at this point. So I would recommend also to look into the configuration of the VM in VirtualBox.